# What RPC method / CLI command to use to query validators' commission changes?

Tags: solana-cli, validator, cli

How to get validators' commission changes along with timestamp and epoch number. What RPC method and/or CLI command to use for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not really a direct way to "monitor" or track a validator's commission changes via the CLI/RPC.

You would either need to use some sort of indexing service or build something yourself to monitor for the changes, likely using Geyser.

You can always get the current commission for all the validators via the Solana CLI. Then once you have the list of validators, their identity account and vote account address to track when the `vote-update-commission` instruction is processed by the chain.

#### Get current commission via CLI

Using this command, you can get the list of all the validators of the Solana cluster your CLI is configured for (e.g. devnet, testnet, mainnet-beta):

```
solana validators
```

##### Example output:

*(simplified for smaller output)*

```
nick@solana:~$ solana validators
  Identity                                      Vote Account                            Commission  Last Vote        Root Slot     Skip Rate  Credits  Version    Active Stake
⚠️ 7yMMUa153jRnkdnQMyiccvzdz66qxwR7b5mPPGsHNdS8  3nA5h4nmfDd4VJUvpD4nnU6VY5fVbRVo6pnvVzR5QCKn  100%  205161097        205161066          -           0  unknown         0.997717120 SOL (0.00%)
  dv1ZAGvdsz5hHLwWXsVnM94hWf1pjbKVau1QVkaMJ92   5ZWgXcyqrrNpQHCme5SdC5hCeYb2o3fEJhF7Gok3bTVN  100%  210613131 (  0)  210613100 (  0)   0.00%   228870  1.14.17  38001333.231257752 SOL (24.97%)
  dv3qDFk1DTF36Z62bNvrCXe9sKATA6xvVy6A798xxAS   vgcDar2pryHvMgPkKaZfh8pQy4BJxv7SpwUG7zinWjG   100%  210613131 (  0)  210613100 (  0)   0.00%   228870  1.14.17  38002062.442825995 SOL (24.97%)

Average Stake-Weighted Skip Rate: 0.07%
Average Unweighted Skip Rate:     46.15%

Active Stake: 152173824.820887029 SOL
Current Stake: 152056659.443439722 SOL (99.92%)
Delinquent Stake: 117165.377447316 SOL (0.08%)

Stake By Version:
1.13.6   -    0 current validators ( 0.00%),   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.12  -    1 current validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.13  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%),   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.14.16  -    1 current validators ( 0.02%),   2 delinquent validators ( 0.07%)
1.14.17  -    5 current validators (99.90%)
unknown  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%),  30 delinquent validators ( 0.01%)
```